# cocos2d-android documentation

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am developing android game using opensource cocos2d-android-1 library available [here](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/) . I also developed demo application using this [tutorial](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/).

Now I want to do further development but I am not getting any documentation for this library and how to use library. If anybody knows any blog, forum, documentation for this library project please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) instead. It is also a port of cocos2d-iphone but with more platforms, a better documentation and a wider community than cocos2d-android (but still not as good as cocos2d-iphone).

It's probably a bit more painful to start because you need to understand how to run native code on android but you probably won't regret it when you decide to port your game on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

many example is available on the github for cocos2d-android and documentation is not in large scale but you can handle most of the things from the test sample which is available in the cocos2d-andriod . if you getting any problem ..post here to get the answer or help..

Comment: hmm ... and this differs/enhances from/on the accepted answer in that..?